# notification from producer thread is not reaching to consumer thread once single item is produced

Tags: c++, linux, mutex, semaphore, producer-consumer

in below code snippet it looks like notification from producer thread to consumer thread is not reaching once producer produce an single item and due to this behavior once producer has finished generating items equivalent to buffer size then only consumer has started consuming items . Can anybody suggest How we should approach to fix this issue using semaphore.

```
 #include <iostream>
#include <queue>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <thread>
#include <functional>
const int BUFFER_SIZE = 3;

class Buffer {
public:
    sem_t sem_full;
    sem_t sem_empty;
    std::queue<int> buffer;

    Buffer() {
        sem_init(&sem_full, 0, BUFFER_SIZE);
        sem_init(&sem_empty, 0, 0);
    }

    void producer() {
        while (true) {
            sem_wait(&sem_full);
            int item = rand() % 10;
            buffer.push(item);
            std::cout << "Producer added " << item << std::endl;
            sem_post(&sem_empty);

            if (buffer.size() == BUFFER_SIZE) {
                std::cout << "Buffer is full, terminating producer thread" << std::endl;
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    void consumer() {
        while (true) {
            sem_wait(&sem_empty);
            int item = buffer.front();
            buffer.pop();
            std::cout << "Consumer removed " << item << std::endl;
            sem_post(&sem_full);

            if (buffer.empty()) {
                std::cout << "Buffer is empty, terminating consumer thread" << std::endl;
                return;
            }
        }
    }
};

int main() {
    Buffer buffer;
    std::thread producer(std::bind(&Buffer::producer, &buffer));
    std::thread consumer(std::bind(&Buffer::consumer, &buffer));

    producer.join();
    consumer.join();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `std::queue` is not thread-safe, you cannot call `push` and `pull` in parallel. But not sure whether your semaphores guarantee exclusive access, I doubt that.

Comment: I tried to add std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mtx);after sem_wait for exclusive access but it didn't work.

Comment: Also to signal from one thread to another there is [std::condition_variable](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable) (I would not use "semaphore.h"). The name is a bit confusing since it is more a signal then a variable. And you need to use it in combination with a lock (std::unique_lock) and a variable, eg. queue's count. So when you queue an item (from within a lock) then you can use std::condition_variable's notify_all function. In other thread use condition_variables wait function (the one with predicate!).

Comment: Do you mean to say semaphore usage is not required here and std::condition_variable needs to be used for notification ?

Comment: @user2907032 That's the usual approach, yes

Comment: does it means  sem_post(&sem_empty) won't take control from producer thread to consumer thread  similar to notify_one()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use binary semaphore here to achieve this behavior without using condition variable to synchronize this.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <thread>
#include <functional>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <mutex>
#include <atomic>
const int BUFFER_SIZE = 4;

class Buffer {
public:
    sem_t sem_full;
    sem_t sem_empty;
    std::queue<int> buffer;
    std::condition_variable cv;
    std::mutex m;
    int buffer_full_count {0};
   

    Buffer() {
        sem_init(&sem_full, 0, 1);
        sem_init(&sem_empty, 0, 0);
    }

    void producer() {
        while (true) {
            sem_wait(&sem_full);
            
             if (buffer_full_count == BUFFER_SIZE) {
                std::cout << "Buffer is full, terminating producer thread" << std::endl;
                return;
            }
            std::unique_lock <std::mutex> lock(m);
            int item = rand() % 10;
            buffer.push(item);
            buffer_full_count++;
            std::cout << "Producer added " << item << std::endl;
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
            sem_post(&sem_empty);
            
        }
    }

    void consumer() {
       
        while (buffer_full_count != BUFFER_SIZE) {
            sem_wait(&sem_empty);
            std::unique_lock <std::mutex> lock(m);
            
            int item = buffer.front();
            buffer.pop();
            std::cout << "Consumer removed " << item << std::endl;
            sem_post(&sem_full);

        }
    }
};

int main() {
    Buffer buffer;
    std::thread producer(std::bind(&Buffer::producer, &buffer));
    std::thread consumer(std::bind(&Buffer::consumer, &buffer));

    producer.join();
    consumer.join();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: wow what a answer as i was expecting same behavior using semaphore . Thank you very much, I appreciate this.

Comment: and it is achieved without using condition variable and in this approach any number of items can be added and same number of items can be removed if we use as a countingsemaphore .